# Controls bar does not fade away in fullscreen mode when using video.js player

Tags: html5-video

I'm using the video.js video player.  After going to fullscreen, the control bar does not fade out.  How do I get the control to fade out in fullscreen mode.   When not in fullsreen mode, the control bar fades away after a few seconds.

Comment: In what browser/version are you seeing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The control bar hiding issue has been fixed and will be released with version 4.2.

There's a writeup on the changes.
http://blog.videojs.com/post/57828375480/hiding-and-showing-video-player-controls